# The best way to express "somebody chosen something that is also chosen by many others"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

I am looking for the best way to express the meaning of **"somebody chosen something that is also chosen by many others because it is the best in the field"**.

> -The A company chosed this B company as their provider too.
>
> -The A company have also chosen this B company as their provider.
>
> -The A company chosen this B company as their provider like many other.
>
> -The A company just like other companies chosen B company as their provider.

**What is the best/correct way to express this?**

Anything other than my examples also appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to phrase this would be "The A company, like many others, chose/has chosen the B company as their provider" 
Or you could even go further and say "The A company, like many others, chose / have chosen B company as their provider, due to [insert reason]".

- "The A company **chosed this** B company as their provider too." This is grammatically incorrect. Chosed does not exist; it is chose.
- "The A company have **also** chosen this B company as their provider." Also is good, however I feel that it does not convey the message as strongly as you would like.
- "The A company **chosen** this B company as their provider like many **other**." You should have written "has chosen" and "like many others".
- "The A company **just like other companies chosen** B company as their provider. You need to use commas here and "has chosen": "The A company, just like other companies, has chosen the B company as their provider.

Comment: not bad at all! but this would be a header of an article so reason can be inserted inside it. so 2nd option seems good but "The A company, like many others, have chosen the B company as their provider" sounds more like a news writer to me. It should be a thrustable opinion based header to create some common sense.

Comment: If it is a header of an article, maybe you could try and use something short and snappy like "B company prides itself as A company follows crowd and chooses them as their provider" or "B company basques in the glory as A company opts for their provider services"?